# Как правильно сохранить из richTextBox'a в *.html

Tags: c#

Всем привет, скажите как надо правильно сохранить файл, чтобы при просмотре браузером были русские слова, один и тот же код использовал в своей программе и NotePad++, у меня всё не по русски, а у него всё нормально.

Использую браузер IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После тега <title> </title>
Добавьте **<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />**
Скопипастил я текст в richTextBox. На нажатие кнопки сделал такое действие

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Write text to file
    StreamWriter streamwriter = new StreamWriter(@"D:\index.html");
    streamwriter.Write(richTextBox1.Text);
    streamwriter.Close();
    //end write text
}
```

Всё сохраняется в html-файл, который нормально открывается без кракозябр. Но без указания <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> у меня тоже кракозябры.